# nginx - https connection doesn't work

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a server where I use nginx (+ certbot to generate ssl certificates ), when I try to access my site using http it works fine but when I try to accees it using https it doesn't work, I have the message `This site can’t be reached` in brwser.

nginx config:

```
...
listen 443 ssl http2;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /path/to/my/cert;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/cert_key;
...
```

also I checked if the 443 port is open, it seems to be ok:

```
sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":443 "

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          67057870   10224/nginx: master
```

Also I checked iptables rules, it seems to be ok too:

```
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`
```

Any idea what can be the problem??

Thank you

Comment: I faced the same problem: created and validated usual SSL certificates, set up NginX, and it runs well, but HTTPS is not working :(